# How to share data between hooks in React (coordinating loosely related components)

Tags: reactjs, animation, events, design-patterns

Say I want to create a complicated, coordinated animation that involves the following:

1. The parent knowing when certain children are finished animating.
2. The children knowing when certain unrelated nodes in the DOM tree are done animating.

The standard way to do this would be to create a central "dispatcher" object sort of thing, and then register all the elements accordingly to it. Then when children are done, parent is done, etc.

But how do you do this with React hooks?

```
function ComponentA() {
  when b is done, animate c and d
  when d is done, animate self
  <div>
    <ComponentB animator={animator}/>
    <ComponentC animator={animator}/>
    <ComponentD animator={animator}/>
  </div>
}

function ComponentB() {
  animate div
}

function ComponentC() {
  when c starts, animate x, then animate y, how?
  <ComponentX animator={animator}/>
  <ComponentY animator={animator}/>
}

function ComponentD() {
  animate b, how?
}

function ComponentX() {
  animate div
}

function ComponentY() {
  animate div
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a way to track when an animation is done, you can simply pass callbacks to each child to let the parent know when they've animated and then coordinate the animations with [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Something like:

```
function ComponentA() {
  const [statusB, setStatusB] = useState('idle')
  const [statusC, setStatusC] = useState('idle')
  const [statusD, setStatusD] = useState('idle')
  // etc...

  useEffect(() => {
    // if componentB is idle, begin animating
    if(statusB === "idle"){
      setStatusB("active");
      return;
    }

    // if componentB is done and component C and D are idle, begin animating them
    if(statusB === "complete" && statusC === statusD === "idle"){
      setStatusC("active");
      return;
    }

    // the rest of your animation dispatch handlers...
  }, [statusB, statusC, statusD])

  return (<div>
    <ComponentB
      status={statusB}
      whenAnimated={() => setStatusB("complete")}
      animator={animator}
    />
    <ComponentC
      status={statusC}
      whenAnimated={() => setStatusC("complete")}
      animator={animator}
    />
    <ComponentD
      status={statusD}
      whenAnimated={() => setStatusD("complete")}
      animator={animator}
    />
  </div>);
}
```

While I don't know how you're animating this, the general idea/pattern for the children would be:

```
function ComponentB({status, setStatus, animator}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if(status === "active") { /* begin animation */ }
    // set up listener to trigger a call to setStatus("
  }, [status]); // To prevent rerenders - see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

  return animated div
}
```

You could also reuse this pattern in ComponentC to manage animating Components X and Y, and you won't need to worry about animating B from D, since that's handled by the parent component.